# How to make responsive background?

Tags: html, css, background

My question is:

Is there any possibility to make something like responsive background ?
What I mean is if there is a possibility that if I go to my website from the mobile phone (e.g. 840px width) my background will automatically fit to my screen but other content from my website will have the same size? And other question is if I can stop it on... lets say 1920px width ?

I don't really have any code yet. I'm just asking. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Use a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
.class{background-size:auto auto;}
@media screen and (max-width 1920px){
    .class{background-size:100% auto;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to fully understand what you're asking for here, but a general tidbit of advice: try out the css property `background-size: cover`. This will cause your background image to take up the entire width *and* height of its container, maintaining aspect ratio and cropping in either direction as necessary.

Its pretty smart, and has pretty good browser support. More info can be found at the link below:

ref: [CSS-Tricks: Perfect Full Page Background Image](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a fixed wrapper for the "background" image with 100% width/height. Tha bakground should be used as a normal image, resized according to it's parent wrapper. The content can be inside another wrapper overlaying the previous one.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `css` background-cover property as this will automatically re-size your image to fit the browser. If you could even use media query to serve up different sized image so it would take up less bandwidth and look better

```
html,body{
background: url(img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover; /* For WebKit*/
-moz-background-size: cover;    /* Mozilla*/
-o-background-size: cover;      /* Opera*/
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.